# Getting object name from string (C# / XNA)

Tags: c#, string, xna, integer, converters

I want to write a kind of command line debug feature in my game that allows the user to type in the name of a variable:

```
int number = 38;
```

...and access the value of that variable, simply by typing in "number", or whatever the name of that variable might be.
Is there some way to turn a string into a variable name, or get a value of a variable from an equivalent string like this?

```
return GetVariable("number");
```

Or is this the completely wrong way to do this? Is there any other way to get the value of any variable, anytime, simply by typing it in someplace?

**SOLUTION**

So here is what people should use:

```
public static T getFromString<T>(object context, string get)
    {
        var use = context;
        BindingFlags bindFlags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static;
        FieldInfo field = use.GetType().GetField(get, bindFlags);
        Object value = field.GetValue(use);
        return (T)value;
    }
```

THIS CODE DOES WORK. You just have to make sure your variable is defined in the class like Foo below. Yay!

Edit: I edited the method again, now it returns the variable with the type, and with your own context. Use it like this:

```
getFromString<int>(Game1, "number");
```

Comment: try reflection techniques

Comment: Unfortunately I know nothing about reflection. I've heard of it though.

Comment: check this link  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/55710/Reflection-in-NET

Comment: If your variable types are same, use a simple `Dictionary`

Comment: Using a dictionary really just defeats the purpose of having a convenient way to get the value of ANY variable. With a dictionary I have to declare which variables i want to be able to get the value of before-hand. I have A LOT of variables. It's simply not convenient or helpful.

Comment: @Lemoncreme No need to update the question to say "resolved" -- simply click the checkmark to the left of the answer that helped you to a solution.  This will identify the question as being resolved to other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already described you need to use reflection or a dictionary lookup. For reflection it would be something like (assuming private instance field):

```
FieldInfo field = type.GetField(fieldName, bindFlags);
Object value field.GetValue(instance);
```

GetValue returns an Object. If you are returning to the console, you probably want to call  and Console.WriteLine(value.ToString()).

**Update**

Updated based on your comment below. I suggest that you refer to the links on reflection that have already been provided in the comments. I always find it easiest to start with a working example, so I have provided one below. This should achieve what you wanted. You may want to tweak it to suit your specific requirements or application.

```
class Program
{
    public class Foo
    {
        int number = 38;
    }

    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo(); //create a new instance of the type that contains variable that you want the value of
        BindingFlags bindFlags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static; //define binding flags
        FieldInfo field = foo.GetType().GetField( "number", bindFlags ); //get the field from the object that has this name
        Object value = field.GetValue( foo ); //get the value of the field.
        Console.WriteLine( value.ToString() ); //output the value to the console.
    }
}
```

Comment: Your assuming I know something about reflection.I seriously don't know ANYTHING about reflection, so this answer helps me none. Would you mind making a more in-depth answer? Sorry for not understanding.

Comment: Thank you! Too bad I get a NULL REFERENCE EXCEPTION on FieldInfo. I did change it a bit...

Comment: I edited my original question to contain my version of your code.

Comment: @Lemoncreme - you should be able to paste the code above into a new console application and run it to see it working. Then work back from what is difference between mine and yours. I got to step out, but hopefully you are close. I will check back later. Good luck.

Comment: Oh yes this works! Thank you so much! My variable number was in the wrong context!

Comment: @Lemoncreme - excellent, glad to help. Please accept the answer (click the tick).